# Check if the full path to multiple files are valid

Tags: linux, unix

Say I have 1000 files and full path to them (example, `mylist`). I may have some of the files (i.e. full paths) invalid. Is there any unix/linux method to check whether a list of files exist in the directories?
for example, I have these three files where file3.txt doesn't exist in mypath, but it exist in `mypath/mypath2/file3.txt`. I want to identify that this file doesn't exist.

mylist:

```
mypath/mypath2/file1.txt
mypath/mypath2/file2.txt
mypath/file3.txt
```

Comment: the list of files  in `mylist` is available in a separate file? How would like to check the files to be checked? iIs it possible to have them all in a single file to check against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of files in a file called `mylist`:

```
while read -r filepath; do
  if [[ -f "$filepath" ]]; then
    echo "File '$filepath' exists"
  else
    echo "File '$filepath' does not exist"
  fi
done <mylist
```

In the above, "exists" means "is a regular file".

Comment: Was not sure if the OP has all the paths to check in a file :) Was looking to provide the exact same answer!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check this would be doing something like this:

```
ls mypath/mypath2/file1.txt mypath/mypath2/file2.txt mypath/file3.txt
```

which then gives

```
mypath/file3.txt: No such file or directory
mypath/mypath2/file1.txt
mypath/mypath2/file2.txt
```